# How to get video stream from webcam in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video-streaming, broadcasting

I need to stream video from my webcam to all user that enter my webpage.

If i currently go to my page i can see myself at the webcam, but I want that every user that browse to my page will see my broadcast live.

I am new to angular, what am I missing here? How can I broadcast to all users that entering my page?

I have this html code:

```
<body>

    <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mainController">


        <webcam   channel="channel"
                on-streaming="onSuccess()"
                on-error="onError(err)"
                on-stream="onStream(stream)">
        </webcam>
        <button ng-click="makeSnapshot()">take picture</button>
        <canvas id="snapshot" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    </div>

    <div class="webcam" ng-transclude></div>

    <div id="stream" ></div>


</body>
```

And my module code:

```
var webcam = angular.module('myapp', ['webcam'])
.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
    var _video = null,
    patData = null;

    $scope.patOpts = { x: 0, y: 0, w: 25, h: 25 };

    $scope.channel = {};

    $scope.webcamError = false;
    $scope.onError = function (err) {

    };

    $scope.onSuccess = function () {

        _video = $scope.channel.video;
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.patOpts.w = _video.width;
            $scope.patOpts.h = _video.height;
            $scope.showDemos = true;
        });
    };

    $scope.onStream = function (stream) {
      //i think it is here i need to add some code for streaming
    };

    $scope.makeSnapshot = function () {

    };

    $scope.downloadSnapshot = function downloadSnapshot(dataURL) {
        window.location.href = dataURL;
    };

    var getVideoData = function getVideoData(x, y, w, h) {

    };

    var sendSnapshotToServer = function sendSnapshotToServer(imgBase64) {
        $scope.snapshotData = imgBase64;
    };
});
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem ?